# Duplicate question, should we flag

Tags: discussion, moderation, duplicates

I was wondering what is the **easiest** way to check if a question is duplicate and how to get the right and accurate duplicate question.
Besides, Sometimes the duplicate question **doesn't match 100%**, it maybe partially answer the current question, should we even flag it as duplicate?

In my case except using my memory to catch the duplicates, i lead a search inside the ESE to try to find out the right duplicate before to flag it. However this procedure isn't **accurate** neither perfect, so any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what I'm doing:

1. Visit Ethereum Stack Exchange everyday.
2. Read every new question, at least the title and try to memorize it.
3. If something sounds *similar* to something you memorized, check the **Related** box on the right sidebar for possible duplicates.
4. If there is no match, use Google (not Stack Exchange`*`) to search for Stack Exchange results with a similar topic.
5. If there is no match, chances are low this is an exact duplicate.

If something does not match 100% it's worth to post a comment and mention the related question. This will create another box in the right sidebar with **Linked** questions, pretty helpful.

---

`*`) I also realized at some point the Stack Exchange search results are often not returning what I'm looking for. The linked and related boxes are helpful, but for searching Stack Exchange I use Google.

Comment: indeed i am visiting ESE every day, the problem happens when i remember a similar post (100%match) but i can't find it, i'll try henceforth the google search instead SE search.